# ASP.NET Javascript cache busting

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pages/cca.js?rev=<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>"></script>
```

Page won't load, I get:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
```

And the site will say:

```
localhost redirected you too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I'm not that familiar with asp.net, can someone point me to my mistake?

EDIT:

Stacktrace: 
[image]

Comment: `<%#` is binding, maybe you want to use `<%=` instead?

Comment: I tried that but the page won't load anymore.

Comment: If it helps, your code works for me: `<script src="/js/pages/cca.js?v=636443597520126724" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: Hmm yea I have no idea what could be the issue, I get no build errors but when trying to access the site I get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Comment: Grasping at straws here, but remove the leading slash for a relative path?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't help. So strange, I don't see any reason this should work. I'm in my Site.Master page is that matters

Comment: I'm not sure I can be of much more help, but the code above without the leading slash works for me, so you may have to post more code to get an answer.

Comment: Prefix `DateTime` with the namespace `System`. So `System.DateTime.Now.Ticks`

Comment: Have the quotes really disappeared in the rendered page?

Comment: Is that the output when you "view source" or when you inspect element? Sometimes its safer to use "view source" [crtl U] in chrome as the developer tools sometimes change things.

Comment: I had to update OP. So before I was sing `<%# %>` which would load the page and show `src="(unknown)"` I was told to use `<%= %>` instead but now the page won't load at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had to wrap it in a rad code block, I'm not sure why but Telerick is the reason:

```
<telerik:RadCodeBlock ID="RadCodeBlock1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pages/cca.js?rev=<%= DateTime.Now.Ticks %>"></script>
</telerik:RadCodeBlock>
```